# How can I perform logistic lasso regression with BIC selection in Python?

Tags: logistic-regression, lasso-regression

The scikit-learn package provides the functions LassoLarsIC() but no option to fit a logistic regression function. How to perform logistic lasso using BIC for model(parameter) selection in python?

logitlasso=LogisticRegression(penalty='l1', solver="saga", max_iter=10000).LassoLarsIC(criterion='bic')

result1=logitlasso.fit(sX, y)